# implicit declaration of function ‘getChar’ in C

Tags: c, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

Some I have this error when I try to compile a program in C.

```
myfunctions.c:27:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getChar’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

Here is line 27:

```
while(myChar = getChar() && myChar != '')
```

I'm calling this in the header:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

Comment: Even after fixing the name, that is almost certainly *not* what you want. Check your precedence. Your loop is equivalent to `while(myChar = (getchar() && myChar != ' '))` You probably want to explicitly say `while((myChar = getchar()) && myChar != ' ')`.

Comment: Hey if this is your exact code, your comparison character is non-existent. Correct that.

Comment: Thanks guys, will this work? 

 while((myChar = getchar()) && (myChar != ' '))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's spelled `getchar`, not `getChar`.  C is case sensitive, and pretty much all the standard C functions' names are all lowercase.

As for why it's "implicitly declared" when it doesn't exist...in older versions of C, if a function name isn't known to the compiler, it's assumed to be a function that returns an `int`.  It's almost as if you said `int getChar();`.  I hear C99 doesn't allow this, but most compilers don't stick to it anyway unless you tell them to.

Comment: Imagine how many fewer bugs programs would have if compilers would actually enforce this (and other issues they ignore the standard on and let slide).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but GCC compiler (win platform) knows `getch()`. But if you switch on `-pedantic` compilation, than this warning occurs.

Solution: use `getchar()` and everything should work ok.